# Disable previously added ng-tag-input when adding new field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have add field button on my form which is having 1 ng-tags-input field in it. After selecting when I click on add field button new ng-tags-input field is added, I want to disable previously added field, as user can click on it and get the recent data coming from server. I tried by using IsDisable technique but its disabling all the fields at the same time.

**HTML**

```
<tags-input ng-model="inputValue" id="{{inputSelected.value}}" display-property="name" placeholder="Select Value" text="text" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false" ng-disabled="">
    <auto-complete source="loadInputValues($query)" min-length="0" load-on-focus="true" load-on-empty="true" max-results-to-show="1000"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
<button type="button" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid" data-ng-show="showAddChoice(choice)" title="Add New Filter" data-ng-click="addNewChoice()" class="btn">Add Filter</button>
```

**JS**

```
    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
            var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
            if (newItemNo <= 10) {
                $scope.choices.push({
                    // 'id' : 'input' + newItemNo,
                    'id' : newItemNo,
                    'name' : 'input' + newItemNo
                });
            }
            //$scope.disableIt = {isDisabled: true};
        };

$scope.showAddChoice = function(choice) {
        return choice.id === $scope.choices[$scope.choices.length - 1].id;
    };
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by myself its by using ng-disabled="choice.id